# Adding iTunesArtwork and iTunesArtwork@2 on cordova ios build

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, build, icons

I`m trying to build ios application with iTunesArtwork and iTunesArtwork@2. I use cordova cli to make ios apps.

I comply all requirements to make it successful:

1. Create iTunesArtwork and iTunesArtwork@2 without extensions
2. Add iTunesArtwork and iTunesArtwork@2 to root project folder

But when i try to look inside ipa file after build it is not contain this icons. Can somebody explain how to do it in a right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't upload the iTunes artwork via Cordova in the same way as the icons, in with the IPA file, they don't get included for the appStore. See Table 1 in  the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html) on the subject. See table one, column 4 "App Store"  - Do not include.

Instead, after submitting your app, logon to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) and upload them there.